# Column must appear in the group by clause error when using partition by

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW episodebydate(tvshowepisodeid, tvshowid, tvshowepisodeairdate) AS (
    SELECT
        tvshowepisodeid,
        tvshowid,
        tvshowepisodeairdate
    FROM
        tvshowepisode
    ORDER BY
        tvshowepisodeairdate
);

WITH episodestocount AS (
    SELECT
        episodebydate.tvshowepisodeid,
        episodebydate.tvshowid,
        episodebydate.tvshowepisodeairdate
    FROM
        episodebydate
    WHERE
        episodebydate.tvshowepisodeairdate between '2018-01-01'
        and '2020-12-31'
)
SELECT
    episodestocount.tvshowid,
    --COUNT(*) AS num_episodes,
    AVG(tvshowepisodereview.score) OVER(PARTITION BY episodestocount.tvshowid ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM
    episodestocount
    INNER JOIN tvshowepisodereview 
         ON episodestocount.tvshowepisodeid = tvshowepisodereview.tvshowepisodeid
GROUP BY
    episodestocount.tvshowid
```

This code is giving me the error

> ERROR: column "tvshowepisodereview.score" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

I tried to fix it by making a partition, but that does not seem to take away the error.

Comment: What is your requirement? If you want `AVG(OVER...)` then you need to remove group by else You can just use `AVG()`.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you don't want a window function:

```
SELECT ec.tvshowid,
    --COUNT(*) AS num_episodes,
       AVG(tvshowepisodereview.score) 
FROM episodestocount ic INNER JOIN
     tvshowepisodereview t
     ON ec.tvshowepisodeid = t.tvshowepisodeid
GROUP BY ec.tvshowid;
```

If you did want another column that was the average of the averages, you would use a window function in conjunction with an aggregation function:

```
SELECT ec.tvshowid,
    --COUNT(*) AS num_episodes,
       AVG(tvshowepisodereview.score),
       AVG(AVG(tvshowepisodereview.score)) OVER ()
FROM episodestocount ic INNER JOIN
     tvshowepisodereview t
     ON ec.tvshowepisodeid = t.tvshowepisodeid
GROUP BY ec.tvshowid;
```